# Satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann theorem

Tags: contour-integration, riemann-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Given $f(z) = f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $i$ is imaginary,
we have the Cauchy-Riemann equations $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$

If the C-R equations are not satisfied, then $f(z)$ is differentiable nowhere.

However, if they are satisfied, then does this mean that  $f(z)$ differentiable everywhere or is further testing required?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, we need the condition that partial derivatives $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ to be continuous on the region on which C-R equations are satisfied.